# listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(...) returns null

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth, null

My Bluetooth Server crashes when trying to create a Bluetooth Server socket.
I already googled a lot and found several answers that I tried, but nothing worked.
I tried the code on several different devices, but the same error appears everywhere.

```
...
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(Var.SERVICE_NAME, UUID.fromString("a70aec2c-19e4-4804-8e3c-557de4e3f558"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
...
```

Error Message:

```
08-01 16:14:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32417): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8045
08-01 16:14:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32417): Process: ... .bluetoothserver, PID: 32417
08-01 16:14:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32417): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 16:14:48.361: E/AndroidRuntime(32417):    at ... .bluetoothserver.communication.BluetoothChat$AcceptThread.run(BluetoothChat.java:103)

08-01 16:14:48.731: E/BluetoothSocket(32417): bindListen, fail to get port number, exception: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
```

What is wrong here? tmp in the following line is null:

```
tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(Var.SERVICE_NAME, UUID.fromString("a70aec2c-19e4-4804-8e3c-557de4e3f558"));
```

Answer (score 0):

listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord failed and rasied IOException, which was ignored and AcceptThread started anyway. mmServerSocket was set to null.

This should fix it:

```
private class Server_Connect_Thread extends Thread {
private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
private boolean running = true;
public Server_Connect_Thread() {
BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
try {
    tmp = bluetooth_adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("NAME", uuid);
} catch (IOException e) {
    bluetooth_show_message("Bluetooth Error! listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord failed. Reason:" + e);
    running = false;
}
mmServerSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
while (running) {
    try {
        socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        bluetooth_show_message("Bluetooth Error! Accepting a connection failed. Reason:" + e);
        break;
    }
...
}
```

The IOException that you got, happens quite often, for example when other devices fails to connect in time, or you are connecting to wrong bluetooth device. In my case it was my neighbours TV set.